# Read text file's lines

Tags: objective-c

I get a remote text file with a specific number of lines. Every line has the same format, and at the end of each one it has a `0x0D`(*carriage return*) and `0x0A`(*new line*).

As a consecuence if I run the following code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *words = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray* lines = [words componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];   

for(NSString *str in lines){
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

I get a blank line between every text line because of those line ending characters. How would you customize my reading and read those lines without those empty ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
NSArray* lines = [words componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`-[NSString enumerateLinesUsingBlock:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW87).

Comment: Is this available in iOs too?

Comment: Yes. "Available in iOS 4.0 and later".

Comment: @KenThomases: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying with: `[words enumerateLinesUsingBlock: ^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@",line);
    }];`  and it doesn't never enter to the loop. How should I use it?

Comment: What you wrote looks right. Are you sure that `words` isn't empty or `nil`? Try logging `words` just before that line.